# How to set a full screen background image

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I am new to Next.js coming from React and cannot seem to figure out how to set a full screen background image using styled components for a hero section. I am easily able to do so using styled components in React by doing something like the code below, but I cannot get it to work in Next.js. Can only get images to display using the built-in Image component. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
const HeroImage = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('IMAGE_PATH');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
`
```

I also just noticed I have the following warning below which I am assuming has something to do with the problem:

Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "sc-bqWxrE dMAojG" Client: "sc-eDvSVe jvXAZS"

Answer (score 0):

looks like your problem could be just that you have to npm install --save styled-components. Styled components was created by React, so it doesn't come in Next.js, so you have to install it first before you use it. You can read more here https://dev.to/britotiagos/how-add-style-components-to-nextjs-and-start-using-it-4kdf

Comment: I did install and import styled components. Other styles work fine, just can't for the life of me figure out get the image to display using background-image. I also know that it is not the image path because it is stored in the public folder and I am able to get the image working with Next.js Image component.